# How can I use `Q.set`?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

According to the [API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) Q provides promise extensions for working with objects, but they don't behave as I would expect.

Consider the following line of code:

```
Q({foo:"bar"}).set("foo","baz").then(console.log);
```

I would have expected `{"foo": "baz"}` to be printed, but it's actually `undefined`.

Do I misuderstand the `set` method, or am I just using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Q.set` is used to augment an object, in the future and it doesn't return the augmented object (in fact, it doesn't return anything at all). That is why you are getting `undefined` in the `console.log`.

You need to use it like this

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};

Q(obj).set("foo", "baz").then(function () {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

This would print

```
{ foo: 'baz' }
```

The property `foo` is set as `baz` in the `obj` and since it is passed along the promise chain, we need to explicitly print it.

---

You can use the sister function, `Q.get`, like this

```
Q(obj).set("foo", "baz").then(function () {
    return Q.get(obj, 'foo');
}).then(console.log);
```

You might be wondering why you cannot do

```
Q(obj).set("foo", "baz").get('foo').then(console.log);
```

It will not work, because of the same reason why `set` didn't work in the first place. **`set` doesn't resolve with the modified object.** That's why we need to explicitly get it from the actual object.

---

FWIW, I found this, `set` not being chainable, bit odd. So, I [submitted a pull request to the Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/pull/705) to change this, and it got rejected.